# I am not able to connect with a local user in a pluggable database(12C)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am not able to connect with a local user in a pluggable database(12C)

Here is relevant code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJTUg.png)

```
SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter session set container=pdborcl;

Session altered.

SQL> create user user1 identified by user1;

User created.

SQL> grant create session,create table to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter user user1 quota unlimited on users;

User altered.


SQL> conn user1/user1
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

Comment: Don't you need to `conn user1/user1@pdborcl`? Setting the container in the first sessionwon't carry through the reconnect, I believe?

Comment: SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter session set container=pdborcl;

Session altered.

SQL> alter database open;

Database altered.

SQL> conn user1/user1@pdborcl
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>     .... DO I NEED TO CREATE A TNS ENTRY OF PDBORCL AS WELL?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit workaround but it worked for me on Oracle 18c Express Edition.First find container name by
`show con_name`

Then connect to user1 as

`conn user1/user1@localhost:1521/xepdb1`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFPpK.png)